# How to allow the rand() in the <cstdlib> library to generate number over 32767?

Tags: c++, random

Because sometimes I wanted to `rand ()` to generate numbers over 32767. Is there have a way to extend the limit of `rand()` and can generate a larger random number for my program. An example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    srand(9439);
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        cout << 1 + (rand() % 500000) << endl;
    }
    
}
```

So, the result never goes beyond 32767.
Is there have a way to let `rand()`generate random numbers over 32767?

Comment: Modern way: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Comment: Don't use `rand()`, use [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: CatWayRoad, Call `rand()` twice.  `(rand()*(RAND_MAX + 1u) + rand()) % 500000`.

Comment: When one of the most popular compilers on the planet has a `RAND_MAX` of 32767, there's really no excuse to use `rand()` any more.  Not when better alternatives have been part of standard C++ for ages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rand()` is a C standard library function that returns an integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, which is *at least* `32767`, but can vary. That depends on the implementation. [I've tested your code](https://godbolt.org/z/c8x4Gz73n) and it works as you would expect. So, in this case it might have something to do with your machine.

Also, as some people have already pointed out, in C++ you're typically better off using [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) rather than using C's `rand()` and `srand()` since they're quite primitive in comparison.

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is notoriously exactly the minimum of 32767 on Windows.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux -- it's 23767 with **some compiler or other** (I'm guessing Microsoft) that runs on Windows. There are standard library implementations for Windows that have a higher limit.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes Microsoft's C++ has that limit.  Nobody was more surprised than I was when I found out.  You could go to some trouble to find and use a different implementation of `rand` but why bother when the standard library already provides great alternatives?

Comment: @MarkRansom -- the point is that Windows is not a compiler.

Comment: @PeteBecker and I was merely confirming your guess that it was Microsoft's compiler.  And I don't know specific numbers, but I'd guess that Microsoft's compiler is an order of magnitude more popular than any others for Windows programming in C++.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- I'll say it again: Windows is not a compiler. Neither is Linux. Questions about C++ programming that say only that they are compiling for Windows or Linux cannot be answered without making assumptions. It's always better to ask **which compiler**, because that's the meaningful information.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use `rand()` then you could call it twice and concatenate the two 32 bit numbers into a 64 bit number.

My C is rusty, so this is C-like pseuodocode:

```
int64 bigRand;
int32 loHalf;
int32 hiHalf;

loHalf = rand();
hiHalf = rand();

bigRand = hiHalf;
bigRand = bigRand << 32;  // bit shift left.
bigRand = bigRand + loHalf;  // Fill in lower bits.
```

This gives `bigRand` as a 64 bit pseudorandom number with all the faults of the original `rand()`.

Comment: When `RANDMAX` is `32767`, this answer is a disaster. The 64-bit result it produces will _always_ have zeros for bits 15 through 31.